# Rails Tutorial Ch8. Michael Hartl - Undefined method remember_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following the railstutorial.org by Michael Hartl and have hit a snag in Chapter 8 when trying to remember the user after a login. The issue is that I am getting an undefined method remember_token. I have gone through and re done all of the steps, reset/rolledback the DB several times and remigrated, gone through all the stack overflow questions I can find and nothing has worked.

Also I have triple checked the syntax and it lists as shown in the tutorial. The program is able to create a user, show the user profile after signup and logout. The unknown method flags when I logout and try to log back in for that user. A lot of the answers on stackoverflow are saying there is not a matching schema in the DB but I have remigrated and checked it and everything is a match. Including several DB:drop commands and then DB:migrate.

The section of the tutorial giving me trouble starts with 8.4.1 Remember token and digest, chapter 8 link: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out

I appreciate the help, can't seem to catch a break with this one!
  Full error message: 
[Picture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYsJ8.jpg)

```
**Error message received through the test:**
ERROR["test_login_with_valid_inforamtion_followed_by_logout", UsersLoginTest, 2016-01-20 10:04:41 +0000]
 test_login_with_valid_inforamtion_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest (1453284281.57s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `remember_token=' for #<User:0x00000009688838>
            app/models/user.rb:28:in `remember'
            app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `remember'
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        app/models/user.rb:28:in `remember'
        app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `remember'
        app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

**user.rb file**

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :remeber_token

 #Returns the hash digest of the given string
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

 #Returns a random token
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end


 #Remembers a user in the database for use in persisten sessions
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private 


    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

**sessions_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      remember user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user

    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

**_add_remember_digest_to_users.rb**

```
class AddRememberDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_digest, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> attr_accessor :remeber_token

You have a typo.

The above code needs to be:

`attr_accessor :remember_token`

Comment: wow. I looked at that three times and missed it. I knew it was something easy like that. Thanks!